# Subtrees of decision tree for comparison sort are recurrences?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, sorting, trees, decision-tree

Consider sorting on $n$ distinct elements, where all $n!$ permutations are possible. I think a decision tree for comparison sort can can be uniquely characterized as $T(a,n!)$ where $a$ is the comparison sort algorithm and $n!$ is the number of leaves. I believe there's a bijection between number of leaves and the number of elements to sort (input size).

Suppose the left subtree of $T(a,n!)$  has $x!$ leaves, can we say the left subtree is $T(a,x!)$ ? ie. same as the decision tree of the same algorithm $a$ sorting on $x$ elements ? (we may generalize factorial to real number using gamma function)

by same I mean having exactly the same structure. Also I'm very new to decision tree for comparison sort so I only know its basic properties like

- they all have $\ge n!$ leaves. ($n!$ when input elements distinct)
- they're all full binary trees
- internal nodes represent indices in comparison, leaves represent permutation of indices that produce the only one sorted output